# dotCover and xUnit on a .net Core project

Tags: .net-core, xunit, dotcover, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to generate a code coverage report file from dotCover while my tests are done with xUnit.

The command I run is `dotCover analyse coverage.xml`
My `coverage.xml` file looks like that:

```
<AnalyzeParams>
  <TargetExecutable>C:\Users\my.name\.nuget\packages\dotnet-xunit\2.3.0\tools\net452\xunit.console.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>Factures.Services.dll</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>Services\Factures.Services.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>dotCover.html</Output>
  <ReportType>html</ReportType>
</AnalyzeParams>
```

However I get the following error message:

```
could not find xunit.dll (v1) or xunit.execution.*.dll (v2) in C:\...\Services\Factures.Services.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following for the `coverage.xml` instead:

```
<AnalyzeParams>
  <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>test Factures.Services.csproj</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>Services\Factures.Services.Tests\</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>dotCover.html</Output>
  <ReportType>html</ReportType> 
</AnalyzeParams>
```

Execution stays `dotCover analyse coverage.xml`

Comment: Tks, it did run whitout errors but the resulting html file has nothing (while there are tests in my project of course).

Comment: I think the reason I have an empty result file is that I'm using xUnit and not MsTest and `dotnet test` doesn't run xUnit tests..

Comment: Indeed, when I run `dotnet test` from the cmd window, it says "no tests available".

Comment: For me it works without any references in the csproj file. But seems you found a way to get it running. Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@fabian-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8821464/fabian-s) for his help into finding the solution.

If you have the following line into your test project csproj file (as per xUnit [doc](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core)):

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
```

then for each test project use the following and then merge your reports (see dotCover [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html)):

```
<AnalyzeParams>
  <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>xunit</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>Services\Factures.services.test</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>dotCover.html</Output>
  <ReportType>html</ReportType> 
</AnalyzeParams>
```

However, if you have the following line into each of your test project csproj file (as per Ms [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore2x)):

```
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.3.1" />
```

then use the following for the whole solution:

```
<AnalyzeParams>
  <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>test</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>.</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>dotCover.html</Output>
  <ReportType>html</ReportType> 
</AnalyzeParams>
```